# to look into to find vs to look up?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

Considering the two following sentences :

1. List directories **to look into to find** ml files.
2. List directories **to look up** ml files.

The number 1 is the original one, the number 2 is the modified one, then have I been well inspired to do this modification? Do they still have the same semantic meaning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number 2 is better than number 1.

First the syntactic: *look into finding ml files* rather than *look into to find* --This suggestion corrects the infinitive of *to find* with the gerund of *finding*, since it comes after a preposition. If you're *looking into* something, you're either researching it or just kinda thinking about it and telling someone that to get off your back.

Semantic: You might also list directories *to look at* ml files, list directories *to find* ml files or *look at* file listings *to find* ml files.